# How to set defaults for a custom Views display?

Tags: 7, views

I'm maintaining a module that provides a new type of Views display (extending the built-in `views_plugin_display_page`).

When the user chooses to add my type of display, I'd like to set up some sensible defaults, like creating a default url path, a default display_title, and some defaults for the additional options my module defines in the display's `options_form`.

How do I set these defaults?

Comment: I wonder if it is possible, because I didn't see a module had this feature.

Answer (score 1):

The class [`views_plugin_display_page`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/plugins%21views_plugin_display_page.inc/class/views_plugin_display_page/7.x-3.x) defines its options (and defaults) through [the 
`views_plugin_display_page::option_definition()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/plugins%21views_plugin_display_page.inc/function/views_plugin_display_page%3A%3Aoption_definition/7.x-3.x) method. This method is just a series overridden methods that extends from the [view base class](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes%21base.inc/function/views_object%3A%3Aoption_definition/7.x-3.x). In a similar manner, your custom plugin can override this method:

```
// defined in your views_plugin_display_page descendant class
function option_definition() {
  $options = parent::option_definition();

  // @TODO: set your own options plus override any other options
  // defined in parent classes. For example: 
  // $options['path'] = array('default' => 'my-default-view-path');

  return $options;
}
```